# Fatal: Required package 'Vcl50' not found

Tags: delphi

I am using Borland Delphi 5 on Windows 7.

When compiling some deplhi code using dcc32.exe from the command line, I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal: Required package 'Vcl50' not found
```

despite the fact that Vcl50.bpl is in C:\Windows\System32 which is in my PATH. I tried putting Vcl50.bpl in the project directory. It still does not get picked up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. After your comment I tried putting Vcl50.bpl in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and adding it to PATH. I still get the error.

Comment: Kind of hard to help, not least because you are in headless chicked mode. You are throwing files here there and everywhere. A standard Delphi installation will put the packages into the system directory. And that's SysWOW64. How did they get into System32? Did you do that? Don't put SysWOW64 in PATH. I repeat, **DO NOT DO THAT**. Back-up everything you have done and tell us how you installed D5.

Comment: I am always in headless chicken mode! SysWOW64 is not in PATH now. I installed Delphi 5 using an install.exe provided to me. I assume the installation put Vcl50.bpl in C:\Windows\System32 - I did not put it there. The installation seems to have worked to a large extent. I can compile the code fine from the IDE. I just get errors when using dcc32 from the command line.

Comment: I don't think the official Borland install.exe could write to system32 since the file system redirector makes that directory unreachable for a 32 bit process. So, if this is not the official Borland install.exe, what is it?

Comment: As far as I know it is an official Borland install.exe. Perhaps I am wrong and I put it in system32 or perhaps it arrived there by some other means. Where should Vcl50.bpl reside on a normal installation? C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi5\Bin ? And why might it not get picked up even when it is in the PATH?

Comment: I don't have D5 installed. I do have D6 which is pretty similar I guess. I have a bunch of D6 runtime .bpl files in SysWOW64. The design-time packages are in <progfiles>\Borland\Delphi6\Bin. I don't think that dcc32.exe depends on .bpl files since it is a C program. My guess is that what's happening is that the compiler can't find the .dcp file. That lives in the Lib folder of your Delphi install. Are you using a shared dcc32.cfg file? Or are you doing it all in the project's .cfg file?

Comment: Thank you! That last comment helped. -U"<progfiles>\Borland\Delphi5\lib" allowed it to find Vcl50.dcp and solved the vcl50 not found problem.

Comment: n situations like that launch SysInternals Process Monitor and trac kwhich exactly file  and where exactly dcc32 tries to open. Alwyas shows you all you need. For exampel you would not waste your time glaring at BPL-file on compiling-phase :-)

Answer (score 2):

On my system it turned out the Library path was wrong in Environment Options.

`tools -> Environment Options -> Library`

Then `Library path`:

```
$(DELPHI)\Lib
$(DELPHI)\Bin
$(DELPHI)\Imports
$(DELPHI)\Projects\Bpl
```

For reference, default values for the rest of the Library tab:

- BPL output directory: `$(DELPHI)\Projects\Bpl`
- DCP Output Directory: `$(DELPHI)\Projects\Bpl`

And finally Browsing Path:

```
$(DELPHI)\source\vcl
$(DELPHI)\source\rtl\Sys
$(DELPHI)\source\rtl\Win
$(DELPHI)\source\Internet
```

Comment: Your library pathes are for Delphi 7, they are not for Delphi 5. There is quite a big difference.

Comment: @dmitry_bond Those are the paths from my install of Delphi 5 on Windows 7. What paths do you have?

Comment: I has this exact problem today, and the solution was to fix a missing entry in **Library Path**. Somehow i had deleted the first one (`$(DELPHI)\Lib`), and that would cause it to be unable to be unable to find `Vcl50.dcp`. The confusion is that the error has nothing to do with `Vcl50.bpl`. Thank you for documenting the correct values.